# add to the end of a line in every file

Tags: sed

I have 25,000 .txt files that all uniformly follow this pattern:

```
String found only at the start of line 1 in every file :Variable text with no pattern
String found only at the start of line 2 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern
String found only at the start of line 3 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern
String found only at the start of line 4 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern
String found only at the start of line 5 in every file :[Variable text with no pattern
```

Can anyone tell me how I'd go about adding a single empty space to the end of line 1, a close parenthesis bracket to the ends of lines 2, 3 and 4, and a close copy bracket to the end of line 5 on every file in the current directory and all sub-directories with sed? I'm new to batch editing text files through the Terminal as of today, and can't seem to figure out how to do this last step on modifying the content of these files despite a few hours looking for a solution.

Thanks for any ideas, solutions, or useful links
Peter Wood
(Using Debian 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following adds the requested characters to the ends of the requested lines.  (I am not sure what a "copy bracket" is, so I used a `]`):

```
$ sed '1s/$/ /; 2,4s/$/)/; 5s/$/\]/' file.txt
String found only at the start of line 1 in every file :Variable text with no pattern 
String found only at the start of line 2 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 3 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 4 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 5 in every file :[Variable text with no pattern]
```

#### How it works

- `1s/$/ /`

  The `1` tells `sed` to apply this substitution only to line `.`$`matches at the end of a line.  The`s` command adds a space at the end of the line.

  Substitute commands have the form `s/old/new/`.  They match on the `old` text and replace it with `new`.  In our case, we want to match at the end of a line, denoted `$`, and place a space there.
- `2,4s/$/)/`

  The `2,4` tells `sed` to apply this substitution only to lines in the range from 2 to 4.  It adds a `)` to the end of the line.
- `5s/$/\]/`

  The `5` tells `sed` to apply this substitution only to line 5.  It adds a `]` to the end of the line.  Because `]` is sed-active, it has to be escaped.

#### Applying it to all your files

To change all your files in-place, making back-up copies with extension `.bak`, use:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/$/ /; 2,4s/$/)/; 5s/$/\]/' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the code John, and in particular thanks for taking the extra time to walk me through it - I'll cut and paste it for future reference. This worked a treat when I put all the files in the same folder and took next to no time at all .... Much better than the AHK script I intended to run on an old XP machine that would have taken literally 87 hours to achieve the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk 'NR==1 {$0=$0" "} NR>1 && NR<5 {$0=$0")"} NR==5 {$0=$0"]"} 1' files*
String found only at the start of line 1 in every file :Variable text with no pattern
String found only at the start of line 2 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 3 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 4 in every file :(Variable text with no pattern)
String found only at the start of line 5 in every file :[Variable text with no pattern]
```

It just test line by line using `NR` (line number) and adds whats needed.
The last `1` is used to print the modified line.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution!